# Principal argument without imaginary components

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

this is a pretty simple question. I have some minor confusion.

If I had complex number:
$$ z = -2 + 0j $$

The prinicpal argument would then be:

$$Arg(z) = \pi, -\pi $$ correct?

And if I also had 
$$ z = 2 +0j $$

The prinicpal argument would then be:

$$ Arg(z) = 0 $$ correct?

Comment: Principal = main (single) argument $0\le\theta\le2\pi$ But in 'principal', you are correct.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the response.

Comment: Oh, according to Joe, its $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]$.  But same thing basically

Comment: But for -2, the value could be either $\pi$ or $-\pi$? Aren't I just choosing different routes to get there?

Comment: Yes, I guess that would be right.  Or you could modify it so $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$ instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if my professor will like that, lol.

Answer (score 0):

The *principal argument* of a complex nonzero number $z$ is defined as the unique $\theta\in]-\pi,\pi]$ such that
$$
z=|z|e^{i\theta}\;\;.
$$
The principal argument is a function so it can't be multivalued.

Comment: We'll can I just choose $ \pi$ or $-\pi$ ? Because using that definition you provided, I got the same answer, by trying both values.

Comment: @user367640 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Principal_value says it can't be $-\pi$.

Comment: @user367640: the very principle of *principal argument* is that there is only one possible value. By convention, the principal argument lies in $(-\pi, \pi]$, so $-\pi$ cannot be a possibility. But this is only a matter of convention, really. If you say that your principal range is $[-2\pi, 0)$, then the only possibility is $-\pi$. But with the classical convention, this is not possible.